# How do I empty dropdown list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am allocating dropdown values from the DB like this.

```
DropDS = someFunctionName()
dropDownID.DataSource = DropDS
dropDownID.DataTextField = DropDS.Tables(0).Columns("columnNameFromDB").ToString()
dropDownID.DataValueField = DropDS.Tables(0).Columns("columnNameFromDB").ToString()
dropDownID.DataBind()
dropDownID.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", "-1"))
dropDownID.SelectedValue = "-1"
```

So, now I want to empty the list on certain condition.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

dropDownID.Items.Clear